How to add JavaScript to an AJAX snippet
I need to customize the fields of a form inside a dialog popup from within an extention. The common form hooks obviously don't work here because I can't address code that's loaded dynamically. Is there a way to inject JavaScript code to the AJAX snippet of a dialog e.g. new case form?

The buildForm hook works for popups too.
TIP: put some logging in a buildForm hook to log the $formName, then visit the page you're interested in.
If you're interested in new case, see https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/opencaserearranger for one example.

form.getTemplate().fetchWith() and addScript() were the missing pieces. Thank you!
